# Cannot delete VirtualBox snapshot due to "insufficient space"

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

My disk is full because my VirtualBox snapshots are consuming a large amount of space. But, I cannot delete the snapshots because there's insufficient space.

I would rather have my snapshots stored on another hard disk. My attempts to delete/merge them have failed.

[image: VirtualBox storage error]

- How do I delete VirtualBox snapshots when disk space is low?
- Also, if it's a better option, how do I move my snapshots?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with VirtualBox 4.3.32.

Comment: The simplest solution is copy every single file associated with the virtual machine to another drive then load that machine.  At which point you can perform a cleanup of the snapshots.

Comment: what do you mean by "load that machine". please forgive my ignorance

Comment: load the copy of the virtual machine so you are not modifying the original virtual machine until you are sure it is going to work.

Comment: I tried cloning the VM but my body parts just got caught in the ceiling fan. So i just deleted it and reloaded it from an OVA I made previously.